# Image gets stuck when using context.rotate to change orientation upon collision [Brick Breakout Game]

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to make a simple Brick Breakout style game using JS, HTML, CSS.  I've done this before so trying to add some additional complexity, including using an image of an asteroid with a tail as the ball.  I'd like to rotate the image so that the asteroid is oriented the correct way(not tail first).  With my current code, when the collision happens my "ball" gets stuck, and the game loop seems to freeze (my paddle isn't moveable either), then after a few seconds it restarts, but you can see the tail of the asteroid in the correct orientation on the other side of the screen.  It's hard to explain, so I put a codepen link up here [Brick breakout](https://codepen.io/anthonydag89/pen/mdENzGN).

Here's the code I believe to be related to the problem, specifically the ctx.rotate function in Ball.JS.

Ball.js:

```
class Ball {
constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    this.image = document.getElementById('ball');
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
    this.posX = 250;
    this.posY = 400;
    this.height = 80;
    this.width = 80;

    this.speed = { x:20, y:20};
};

draw(ctx) {
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
};

update(deltaTime, ctx) {
    if(!deltaTime) return;

    this.posX += this.speed.x/deltaTime;
    this.posY += this.speed.y/deltaTime;

    if(this.posX >= this.gameWidth - this.width) {
        this.speed.x = -this.speed.x;
        ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180)
    };
    if(this.posX <= -15) {
        this.speed.x = -this.speed.x;
    }
    if(this.posY >= this.gameHeight - this.height +15 || this.posY <= -15) {
        this.speed.y = -this.speed.y;
    };
};
};
```

Index.js:

```
import Paddle from '/paddle.js';
import inputHandler from '/input.js';
import Ball from '/ball.js';

const canvas = document.getElementById('gameScreen');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const gameWidth = 800;
const gameHeight = 500;

const paddle = new Paddle(gameWidth, gameHeight);

const ball = new Ball(gameWidth, gameHeight);
new inputHandler(paddle);

let lastTime = 0;

const gameLoop = timeStamp => {
let deltaTime = timeStamp - lastTime;
lastTime = timeStamp

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 500);
paddle.update(deltaTime);
paddle.draw(ctx);
ball.draw(ctx);
ball.update(deltaTime, ctx)

requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop)
};

gameLoop();
```

Comment: Not I think the basic problem, but is there a reason you update the paddle then draw it but draw the ball before doing its update? When you rotate the canvas context won’t it stay rotated, even for the paddle or does it get reset somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The game was crashing because whole canvas was rotated so the ball coordinates were off. You need to remove line **ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180)** from the update function.

You can rotate just the image using **ctx.save()** and **ctx.restore** in the draw function. This way you can translate and rotate the picture and then restore after the image is drawn.

```
class Ball {
    constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
        this.image = document.getElementById('ball');
        this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
        this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
        this.posX = 250;
        this.posY = 400;
        this.height = 80;
        this.width = 80;

        this.speed = { x:20, y:20};
    };

    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate( this.posX, this.posY );
        
        let rotation = 0
        if(this.speed.y<0){
            rotation = Math.PI
        }else{
            rotation = 0
        }

        if(this.speed.x<0&&this.speed.y<0){
            rotation-=Math.PI/2
        }

        ctx.rotate( rotation );
        ctx.translate( -this.posX, -this.posY );
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.restore()
    };

    update(deltaTime, ctx) {
        if(!deltaTime) return;

        this.posX += this.speed.x/deltaTime;
        this.posY += this.speed.y/deltaTime;
    
        if(this.posX >= this.gameWidth - this.width) {
            this.speed.x = -this.speed.x;
        };
        if(this.posX <= -15) {
            this.speed.x = -this.speed.x;
        }
        if(this.posY >= this.gameHeight - this.height +15 || this.posY <= -15) {
            this.speed.y = -this.speed.y;
        };
    };
};
```